# Call and sms option same time when taping a label

Tags: ios, swift, sms, call

I am trying to make a contact phone book app that by taping the phone number, if will launch to open call app or sms app.

So far I have found these options:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(tlfURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
UIApplication.shared.open(smsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Those must be called separately.
Is there a way to trigger both of them, Call and Sms launch option, by taping on the label once?

If not any suggestions how to implement this ? UIActivityViewController ?

Thanks

Comment: UIActivityViewController is much better because then the user sees a standard set of options and they get to choose what they want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a

```
UIAlertController
```

with

```
preferredStyle: .actionSheet
```

it will help you present multiple options to the user to let them pick what they want to do. It would looks something like this:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet) // makes a new UIAlertController with no title or message

    // makes a new UIAlertAction to call on tap
    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .default) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.open(tlfURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    // makes a new UIAlertAction to sms on tap
    let smsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SMS", style: .default) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.open(smsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    // makes a new cancel action so the user can decide not to take any actions
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    // add the actions to the UIAlertController
    alertController.addAction(callAction)
    alertController.addAction(smsAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // present the UIAlertController to the user so they can interact with it
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```